# How to quote string in python using "mysql.connector"

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm newbie to python and writing a script that reads json file, do some processing, and generate SQL statements that finally is written to a sql file. I'm using `mysql.connector` on `python 3.6` to create connection.
From that connection object, I need to quote the parameters that are binded to the SQL. I'm not executing SQL from python, otherwise python itself would have handled it. 
Also, I'm not directly using single/double quotes as my value may contain these quotes and sql will break. Moreover, there are many characters that needs to be quoted, so can't be sure after replacing just one character (say single quote).

Sample Code:

```
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pwd, database=database, host=host)
sql = "INSERT INTO customer_data VALUES "

values = "(default, %s, %s, %s);" % (
            cust_record["name"],
            cust_record["address"],
            comment["date"]
            )

fh.write("%s %s\n" % (sql, values))
```

It writes string as it is while creating insert statement, I avoided putting hardcoded single quotes.

I also tried this on console for testing:

```
name = 'kam\al'
str = ("my name is %s" % name)
con.converter.escape(str)
```

It gives: `'my name is kam\x07l'`, without quoting the name string.
Same in perl can be achieved via perl DBI's [quote](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.640/DBI.pm#quote) method.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you would shown a piece of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Edited to add sample code and tested on console too. I need to generate SQL statements and write them in a file so that DBA can directly run it using source command

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

You can use `convert_to_mysql()` if you want both, and construct the connection in a different way. Here's an example (Python 3.6):

```py
import _mysql_connector
ccnx.connect(user='abc', database='xyz', password='def')
params = ('sdgs\adsgsdg', 'sdgs^&%"', "sdgsdg'") 
print(ccnx.convert_to_mysql(*params))
```

Will output:

```
(b"'sdgs\x07dsgsdg'", b'\'sdgs^&%\\"\'', b"'sdgsdg\\''")
```

They are already quoted and escaped. Note that they are bytes (python 3) so you might need to convert them to `str` (depndeing on your python version.

See:
[_mysql_connector.MySQL.convert_to_mysql() Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-convert-to-mysql.html)

**Old answer**

Don't construct queries that way, you may open yourself to SQL injection and other issues.

Use prepared statements, let the driver do the quoting for you, e.g:

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES (%s)"
name = "Some name' who cares"

cursor.execute(stmt, (name,))
```

For more info see:
[Inserting Data Using Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)

Comment: I don't want to execute from python, I just need to write insert statements in a file and it will be run by DBA. At the moment, don't think for injection, as I'm going to run it just once, after successful query preparation this script will be deleted

Comment: I'm using "mysql.connector", Is there anything we can do using this module?

Comment: That module should come with `mysql.connector`. It's also in their docs (I linked to them in the answer).

Comment: My system has installed `mysql.connector`. I'm not sure whether `_mysql_connector` comes with `mysql.connector`, but the converse is not true. Former is for C API, that can be used with flag `use_pure=False` in the latter one.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext-reference.html

Comment: Did you try it? I've done a test in a clean virtualenv, ran `pip install mysql-connector-python`, then in a python shell `import _mysql_connector` and it works.

Comment: Yes, I've tried, retried after your comment (this time on Windows system). `pip3 install mysql-connector-python` then in python shell (2.7 & 3.6) `import _mysql_connector`. It gives `ImportError: No module named _mysql_connector`. On the other hand, I'm able to do `import mysql.connector`.

Comment: Can you try using the MSI installer instead of pip? It should include the c extension.

Comment: Stable version not available for 3.6, tried installing dev release. It says `it supports only python 3.6 installed using msi installer`. As far as I remember I have installed it from msi, but not sure about this. I'll check from scratch on some other pc, thanks for your efforts

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/2.0.html